# Randomizing ranges with no duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

I’m a parent on a soccer team, and we are organizing lists for what parents bring as far as snacks and supplies to each game. There are 16 parents.

- Each parent is capable of bringing: forks, knives, cups, ice, plates, spoons, oranges, water, trash bags, and sunscreen.
- Exactly three unique parents are capable of bringing one of the following: Grapes, Sandwiches, Candy, Apple Slices, Rolling carts, Uniform Cleaner or Lawn Chairs
- Two unique parents are capable of bringing: Dog fencing or Medical Kits
- Two parents can bring Medical Kits or Lawn Chairs

I want to add each parent’s list of available items, and use Google Sheets to roll 12 instances of data, in which each parent brings a unique item. No Duplicates. There will be a few left over that no parent brings, which the coach will bring. I’d like that information displayed as well. I think using a combination of Filter and RandBetween can accomplish this?

How can I do this using Google Sheets, assuming I have already created a sheet (tab) with another tab that lists Col A with each parent’s name, and Cols B, C, etc, with a list of each item they are capable of bringing?

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Comment: Sample Document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10ZeYxZcgUy4JQV7m-F3fInpTQBhfb8lig2rvYuomG5w/edit#gid=1259339566

In this, you'll see the "Parent Goodies" tab, and the "Schedule" tab. "Parent Goodies" shows the 16+1 parents, and 19 available items available (or not) to each one. 

I want the "Schedule" tab to have each column listed such that, the items are randomly distributed among the pool of available items uniquely, but also such that they do not violate what a parent can bring.

Ex: Col. B & Col. C show valid combinations of unique randomization, and Col. B <> Col. C.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have something like this lying around. You should be able to leverage [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_CdteLdmO0VarMc6GGiJeJS2wKN65QIH5__GlnMu_g/edit?pli=1#gid=0), just download your own copy. Put your items to randomize in column 'b' and then it will spit out a sorted randomized group in column `d` with this formula:

`=let(sData,filter(A2:B,B2:B<>""),CHOOSECOLS(sort(sData,1,1),2))`

[image]